# How can I get view text from action attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view

I need to get the view text (not rendered html) from some action attribute.

For example:

```
View (someview ) text :  Hello @Name @Surname

[ActionFilter]
public SomeViewAction()
{
    return View(someview,someModel);
}

public class ActionFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //here I need get text "Hello @Name @Surname"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had an action filter like this:

```
public class ActionFilterAttribute : FilterAttribute, IResultFilter
{
    public string ViewName { get; set; }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if(viewResult != null)
        {
            var viewName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewName) ? (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewResult.ViewName) ? filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() : viewResult.ViewName) : ViewName;
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            {
                var viewEngine = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
                var razorView = viewEngine.View as RazorView;
                if (razorView != null)
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filterContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(razorView.ViewPath)))
                    {
                        var markups = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you would be able to apply the filter in controller action:

```
    [ActionFilter]
    public ActionResult SomeView()
    {
        //var someview = "SomeView";
        var somemodel = default(object);
        return View(somemodel);
    }
```

Comment: This code throws exception ,because viewResult.ViewName = "" I think

Comment: Did you test with above controller action? I tested, no exception.

Comment: The code above is pseudocode,but if we return View(model),not pointing the view name,the exceprion is occured

Comment: yeah, sure. And we should pass view name to the attribute.